# Spinner items hidden under tablet system bar

Tags: android, spinner, tablet

I have a spinner that will have a varying amount of items. If the spinner is just the right length (6 items in this case) the last item or two will be hid under the tablet system bar, making them unselectable.

From what I understand spinners will automatically either fit the screen (by expanding up instead of down) or become scrollable. This only happens when I press hold and reopen the tablet again.

I think I'm looking for something like this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFitSystemWindows()

but this option is only available in API 16+ and i'm working in API 11.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have also the same problem. No solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I found the solution to my own problem...

spinner.setSystemUiVisibility(int visibility);

It seems like it works no matter what int I use for the visibility parameter. Note this this option is only available in API 11+.

Comment: So you can set it also to visible and the result of the command is, that the spinners are redrawn in the right way?

Comment: I was referring to an actual integer. I know that's not the way it was intended to be used but it works. I think i'm using 2, but like I said I tried a bunch and it still worked

Comment: Just for your information: 2 means SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION. To see what flags are available, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html and search for SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_